# How to change font of MarkerWithLabel Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fonts

How i change a font of a label marker in my application using Google Maps API v3?
Im changing to Lato and still "arial", why? :(
Code:

```
  .labels {
 color: red;
 background-image:url('testemark.png');
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 width: 77px;  
padding-top:5px;
padding-left:7.5px;
height:23px;
}

var marker2 = new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(10,20),
      map: map,
      labelContent: "example2",
      labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 20),
      labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
    });
```

thx

Comment: What are you trying to change it from/to?  What have you tried?

Comment: im trying to change Arial to Lato or Pacifico web fonts but still arial :s

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_MarkerWithLabelB.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps visual refresh - how do disable font Roboto in InfoWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613347/google-maps-visual-refresh-how-do-disable-font-roboto-in-infowindow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `important`-rule to the format:

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif  !important;
```

Comment: If this really is the answer, I am impressed. +1